# getEntityRecord without knowing the post type

Tags: custom-field, javascript, hooks, block-editor

In Gutenberg there's the `getEntityRecord` selector that allows you to get the data of a post of a specific post type:

```
// get the post object of a page with post id = 42
const post = useSelect( ( select ) =>
    select('core').getEntityRecord( 'postType', 'page', 42 )
);
```

My question is, is there a similar selector for when you don't know the post type of a post beforehand? I have a meta field that stores an array of post ids of different post types and right now I'm unable to get the full post objects.

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you'll have to make a [custom endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) which then returns the data of those posts.. Or maybe you could try saving the post type in addition to the post IDs..

Comment: how did you get the post ID? You may already have that information

Comment: Yep, as Sally says, I could store the the post type in the array, too. I was just wondering if there was a way to get the full post data of a post without knowing its post type.

Comment: @leemon how are you getting the post ID? What's the context for the code? Is this in a sidebar component?

Comment: also, if you do not know which kind of entity it is, `wp.data.select('core').getEntitiesByKind('postType')` will list them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, is there a similar selector for when you don't know the post type of a post beforehand?

No, at the current time of writing there is not.

The fundamental problem is that the REST API doesn't provide a generic mechanism for getting a post type given a post ID. You can retrieve a post and it will say `post` but to do this you need to know the type in advance to hit the correct URL.

Since the entity Record API relies on these endpoints, there technically are no post IDs. There's a page record with an ID, or a post record with an ID, etc

So if you want to do this properly, you need to either save the post type, restrict the types allowed for that meta field, or loop through the different entity types to see which ones return a 404 and which one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, you can use the following to get the current post type :

```
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';

const postType = useSelect(
  (select) => select('core/editor').getCurrentPostType(),
  []
);
```

You can then get the following :

```
const { record, isResolving } = useEntityRecord( 'postType', postType, 42 );
```

Or, in an easier way :

```
const editor = useSelect((select) => select('core/editor'));
const post_type = post.getCurrentPost().type;
```