# Using apiFetch for retrieving post data in Gutenberg

Tags: javascript, block-editor, rest-api

In a plugin I'm developing, I registered a custom REST API route to get some post data passing a post id:

```
function rest_api_init() {
    register_rest_route( 'custombase/v1', '/post/(?P<id>[\d]+)', array(
        'methods'             => 'GET',
        'callback'            => 'get_post_rest',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
        'args'                => array(
            'id' => array(
                'validate_callback' => function( $param, $request, $key ) {
                    return is_numeric( $param );
                }
            ),
        ),
    ) );
}

function get_post_rest( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    $post = get_post( $request['id'] );
    if ( is_wp_error( $post ) ) {
        return $post;
    }

    $data = array(
        'ID'    => $post->ID,
        'title' => $post->post_title,
    );

    $response = new WP_REST_Response( $data, 200 );

    return $response;
}
```

I checked and the route is registered correctly as I can get info visiting, for example, the following URL:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/custombase/v1/post/1239
```

This is the result:

```
{"ID":1239,"title":"My example post title"}
```

As I understand, I need to use the `apiFetch` utility to make REST API requests to custom routes in Gutenberg. This is what I'm doing:

```
const mypost = apiFetch( { path: 'custombase/v1/post/1239' } ).then( ( post ) => {
    return post;
} );
```

But, instead of post object, I'm getting a `Promise` with the post object inside when I do a `console.log( mypost )`:

```
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
​<state>: "fulfilled"
​<value>: Array [ {…} ]
​​0: Object { ID: 1239, title: "My example post title" }
​​length: 1
​​<prototype>: Array []
```

How can I get the post object instead?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using a custom endpoint to return post data, why not register the extra fields you wanted and use the get entity API? Then your posts would automatically be retrieved and would be incorporated in the standard post objects, and you could even use standard APIs to save the data. Doing it this way duplicates a lot of internal functionality, and introduces new problems, e.g. how do you tell the different between the current data vs the unsaved edited data?

Comment: as for the promise, this is an asynchronous mechanism, you need to wait for the promise to complete, but that's not a WordPress problem, that's a general javascript problem (and one you shouldn't be trying to solve as this approach is wrong, see my previous comment)

Comment: see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_field/#comment-2145 for an example. If you're doing this because you believe you're improving performance by only retrieving the ID and title, then you are mistaken, the entire post will be fetched including its post meta and terms when `get_post` is called, and even if it was faster, it would still be slower than just bundling the data via the post endpoint and having it pre-added by the block editor so no additional requests are needed

Comment: Yes, I know how to use getEntityRecord to get post data and I'm sure it's way more optimal than using a custom endpoint, but it requires the post type to be specified. I just wanted to try using an agnostic endpoint that doesn't need the post type to be provided.

Comment: So basically this is asking how to fix a solution to this question you asked https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/388796/getentityrecord-without-knowing-the-post-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm getting a `Promise` with the post object inside when I do a
> `console.log( mypost )`

Yes, because [`apiFetch()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-api-fetch/) indeed returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object, and `apiFetch()` doesn't assign the response received from the server to the `mypost` constant, and the return value of your [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) callback is also not going to be assigned to the `mypost` variable.

> How can I get the post object instead?

[As suggested by React](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html), you would want to add `mypost` as a local state in your component, then make your XHR/AJAX request (using `apiFetch()`, the native `window.fetch()`, Axios or whatever) in the [`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) method of a class component, or use the [`useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) in a function component.

Example using `apiFetch()` with `useEffect`:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from '@wordpress/element';
import apiFetch from '@wordpress/api-fetch';

function MyComponent( { post_id } ) {
    const [ error, setError ]       = useState( null );
    const [ mypost, setPost ]       = useState( null );
    const [ isLoaded, setIsLoaded ] = useState( false );

    useEffect( () => {
        apiFetch( { path: `custombase/v1/post/${ post_id }` } ).then(
            ( result ) => {
                setIsLoaded( true );
                setPost( result );
            },
            ( error ) => {
                setIsLoaded( true );
                setError( error );
            }
        );
    }, [ post_id ] );

    if ( error ) {
        return <p>ERROR: { error.message }</p>;
    } else if ( ! isLoaded ) {
        return <p>Loading post { post_id }..</p>;
    } else if ( mypost && mypost.id ) {
        return <h3>Post <i>{ mypost.title || '#' + mypost.id }</i> loaded!</h3>;
    }
    return <p>No such post</p>;
}
// Sample usage: <MyComponent post_id="1239" />
```

#### Alternate Solution: Add an entity for your custom endpoint into the list of entities in the block editor.

1. Add the entity using [`addEntities()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core/#addEntities):

   ```js
   import { dispatch } from '@wordpress/data';

   dispatch( 'core' ).addEntities( [{
       baseURL: '/custombase/v1/post',
       // The 'post' is not a post type - it's the "post" as in /post above. Also, "kind"
       // and "name" are not documented, so let's assume they form the above baseURL..
       kind: 'custombase/v1',
       name: 'post',
       label: 'Post or whatever',
   }] );

   // You can, for example, call the above (i.e. add the entity) before you register your
   // block type.
   ```
2. Then use [`getEntityRecord()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core/#getEntityRecord) to fetch post data from the endpoint:

   ```js
   const mypost = select( 'core' ).getEntityRecord( 'custombase/v1', 'post', 1239 );
   // Note that getEntityRecord() caches the results.
   ```
3. And note that for `getEntityRecord()` to work correctly, your endpoint callback must use the lowercase `id` and *not* `ID`:

   ```php
   // In the get_post_rest() function:

   $data = array(
       'id'    => $post->ID, // use id and *not* ID
       'title' => $post->post_title,
   );
   ```

So for example using [`useSelect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/#useSelect), the above component (`MyComponent`) could now look like so:

```js
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';

function MyComponent( { post_id } ) {
    const { mypost, isLoading } = useSelect( ( select ) => {
        const args = [ 'custombase/v1', 'post', post_id ];

        return {
            mypost: select( 'core' ).getEntityRecord( ...args ),
            isLoading: select( 'core/data' ).isResolving( 'core', 'getEntityRecord', args )
        };
    }, [ post_id ] );

    if ( isLoading ) {
        return <p>Loading post { post_id }..</p>;
    } else if ( mypost && mypost.id ) {
        return <h3>Post <i>{ mypost.title || '#' + mypost.id }</i> loaded!</h3>;
    }
    return <p>No such post</p>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My knowledge of JS/React/Gutenberg is pretty limited and I'm learning as I go along. The async nature of JS is sometimes hard for me to grasp. I didn't know you could add custom entities to the list of entities in the block editor either.

Comment: I could tell, which is also why I posted the answer than just linking to one my past answers.. And I was also once a JS newbie.. but you know, just keep on learning :) And here's a tip: Open the browser console and type `wp.data.select` or `wp.data.dispatch` or even just `wp` and hit the Enter key, and you'd see the list of methods/functions in the `select`, `dispatch`, etc. package. Even better, enable script debugging ([`SCRIPT_DEBUG`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#script_debug)) and it'll be easier for you to spot mistakes/errors in your code. ;)

Comment: BTW, I didn't notice this mistake in your original question: `$data[]`, but `getEntityRecord()` is actually smart enough to return just *one* record.. :)

Comment: Yes, I spotted this mistake while testing some code. I edited my question.

Comment: +100! `addEntities()` is still not documented. As an update, there are hooks called `useEntitiyRecord` and `useEntityRecords` so the above `useSelect()` could _probably_ be rewritten as `const { mypost, isResolving } = useEntityRecord( 'custombase/v1', 'post', { post_id } );` see [blog post](https://developer.wordpress.org/news/2023/05/19/useentityrecords-an-easier-way-to-fetch-wordpress-data/)

Comment: Hi @helgatheviking. Thanks for the +100 :D and also for sharing the link, but we'd use `const { record: mypost, isResolving: isLoading }` if we wanted to retain the same variable names (i.e. `mypost` and `isLoading`).. :) As for the documentation, have you already seen the ["What's an entity" section](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-core-data/#whats-an-entity)? Not all properties were listed there, but at least we could now get a better understanding of the basic props in each entity object.

Comment: yes, good catch! as the variable names that are returned are specific/restricted. I'd not seen that and was def wondering if there's a way to see all defined entities (like in the console or something). This answer got my blocks connected to a custom endpoint when I couldn't find anything else on the web. so thanks again! :)